# Calculating exponents with complex arguments.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I am trying to calculate the exponent $a^b$, where a and b are imaginary numbers, being represented here as 2 element arrays.

I am using the equations for this from wolfram mathworld, that is:
$\left(a[1]+ia[2]\right)^{(b[1]+ib[2])} \left(a\left[1\right]^2+a\left[2\right]^2\right)^{\frac{b\left[1\right]}{2}}e^{\left(-b\left[2\right]\cdot arg\left(a\right)\right)} \left[\cos \left(b\left[1\right]\cdot a_{rg}\left(a\right)+\frac{1}{2}b\left[2\right]\ln \left(a\left[1\right]^2+a\left[2\right]^2\right)\right), \sin \left(b\left[1\right]\cdot a_{rg}\left(a\right)+\frac{1}{2}b\left[2\right]\ln \left(a\left[1\right]^2+a\left[2\right]^2\right)\right)\right]$

I have implemented $arg(z)$ as $arctan\left(\frac{z[2]}{z[1]}\right)$. This works for most values, however it results in weird, incorrect values when the real part of a is negative. Where is the mistake in these equations? I have checked them multiple times, and the only thing I can think is that maybe my arctan is defined in the wrong range, but I checked and it is going from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation from Wolfram looks needlessly complicated. There is a simpler way to compute the complex power $a^b$, but you have to be careful because it is not always perfectly well-defined.

Take for example the real expression $4^{1/2}$: is this equal to $2$? or $-2$? By convention we usually pick the positive one (and negate it separately if the problem calls for the other solution). Similarly, there is a convention whereby we pick the value of the power $a^b$ when there are multiple candidates.

The definition for the general complex exponent is as follows:
\begin{align}
a^b := e^{b \ln a}
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers and $e^{x+yi} := e^x(\cos y + i \sin y)$

The trouble comes in with $\ln a$. In the real numbers, $e^x$ is a one-to-one function and so has a well-defined inverse. Not so in the complex plane. For example: $e^0 = 1$, but so does $e^{2\pi i}$ and $e^{4\pi i}$ and so on. Hence there are multiple candidates for $\ln(1)$ when $\ln$ is allowed to take on complex values. Specifically:
\begin{align}
\ln(1) = 2\pi k i
\end{align}
for any integer $k$.

In general $\ln(z)$ can take on any of these values:
\begin{align}
\ln z = \ln|z| + i \arg z
\end{align}
where $\ln|z|$ is the standard *real-valued* natural log that is well-defined, and $\arg z$ can be *any* of the possible arguments for a complex number (each one a multiple of $2\pi$ away from the others).$\newcommand{\Arg}{\operatorname{Arg}}$

In choosing a single value for $\ln z$ we usually prescribe the *principle* argument $\Arg z$ for the general one $\arg z$:
\begin{align}
\ln z := \ln|z| + i \Arg z
\end{align}
which is restricted to the range $-\pi < \Arg z \leq \pi$. This *principle* log is then used to define the *principle* exponent, so we (finally) get:
\begin{align}
a^b := e^{b\left(\ln|a| + i \Arg a \right)}
\end{align}
$\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}$

Now with all that out of the way, we come to how to compute $\Arg z$. If your $\arctan$ function is computing the standard arctangent, then it should be restricted to the range $-\pi/2 < \arctan \theta < \pi/2$, not $-\pi$ to $\pi$. This, of course, does not cover the full range of possible arguments, and in fact only covers the cases where $\Re(a) > 0$. It will be off by $\pi$ if $\Re(a) < 0$. Thus the correct way to compute an angle is with the following piecewise function:
\begin{align}
\theta =
\begin{cases}
\arctan(y/x) & \text{if $x>0$} \\
\pi + \arctan(y/x) & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
But of course, this does not handle the cases where $x = 0$, and so there are even *more* cases for that. What's more, the angles may not be in the range $(-\pi, \pi]$.$\newcommand{\atan}{\operatorname{atan2}}$

Because of this, most programs provide a function called $\atan(y,x)$ that computes the angle correctly regardless of the sign of $x$ and also in the correct range $(-\pi, \pi]$. Although if yours does not put it in that range for some reason, you can always add or subtract $2\pi$ accordingly to correct it.

Comment: It is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, sorry I miswrote that.

Comment: I used this with atan2 and it works. Thanks for your help.